# How to change color of line according to threshold values in C3.js/D3.js charts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, line, c3.js

I have an array of actual values, it should be just a line and an array of threshold values it should be the second line. When the actual value-line crossed through the threshold line the color of this part of the line should be changed.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    point: {
        r: 5
    },
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04'],
            ['actual value', 230, 120, 300, 50],
            ['threshold', 130, 280, 100, 250],
        ],
        type: 'spline',
        regions: {
            'threshold': [{'style': 'dashed'}]
        },
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please be more specific about your question? Did you expect to change the color of line "actual value" when crossing over "threshold" line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it is done in `c3`, but as you mentioned `d3` in your question, you would use a [threshold scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#threshold-scales) in `d3`.

See [this example from blocks](https://bl.ocks.org/hepplerj/f2f4e5f4a9321428b11614674c741177):

```
var colorThresholdScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.50])
  .range(["#fee5d9", "#fcae91", "#fb6a4a", "#de2d26", "#a50f15"]);
```

The range in a threshold scale always has one more value than the domain.

If the given value is less than the first value in the domain, then the first value in the range is output:

```
colorThresholdScale(0.02); // "#fee5d9"
```

If the input value is greater than the *nth* value in the domain, and less than the *n + 1th* value in the domain, then the *n + 1th* value in the range is output:

```
colorThresholdScale(0.25); // "#fb6a4a"
```

If the input value is greater than the last value in the domain, then the last value in the range is output:

```
colorThresholdScale(0.6); // "#a50f15"
```